# Android studio pushing commit failing

Tags: android, git, github, git-commit

Earlier I was attempting to remove a commit from my commit history, and went through some stackoverflow threads doing stuff like rebasing etc.
Now here I am attempting to push a new commit, but I get this error which I feel is because of what I did earlier.

```
Error rebasing
fatal: update_ref failed for ref 'refs/heads/master': cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/master': ref refs/heads/master is at 9529c90e148e9b2620db0f366587312e75d507b6 but expected 808b9dfbc4141d16a29fadb4bd8171c6fe8f4914
```

Comment: take updated and then commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to rebase first and then submit the checklist, currently the local and remote are at different level.

Just save your changed files, in some tmp directory, do the rebase(Menu->VCS->GIT->Rebase). 
Once origin and remote are at same level, you may manually copy these files from temp, which will be shown in version control section of android studio. You can rightclick changelist and commit and push.

Regards
Ashish